# How to reduce memory consumption in Java application server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a Java application server which processes data from network clients. The problem that I face is the memory consumption of the Java application. What are the effective techniques for reducing the memory consumption in Java applications. Would you please share some experience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a profiler, identify where the memory is consumed, and optimize what should be optimized.

It could be settings (number of threads in the pool, etc.), algorithms, data structures, database queries. It's impossible to know without knowing the internals of the application.

And even then, guessing has a good chance of giving incorrect results. Measuring and analyzing is the best thing to do.